# UIScrollView not scrolling in ios6

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

In my `UIViewController` I have a `UIScrollView` and `UIView`. These are two different view, means `UIView` is not inside `UIScrollView`. I have different view on scrollview that i am setting programmatically and increasing `contentSize`. And this `UIView` is hidden, i am showing is sometimes. The problem is that when i hide this `UIView`, that `UIScrollView` stops scrolling.

Why this happening?

I have set all leading edges to superview of both. Does it matter?
Please guide me.

Hi all, I am sharing the image of my `ViewController Scene`[image]

I am using auto layout (iOS6). `Scroll View ContentSize` is (768,1400) which i am setting in `ViewDidAppear`. The `View` below `Scroll View` is hidden and `Scroll View` is scrolling without any problem.

Now if i show and hide the `View`, the `Scroll View` locks, its not scrollable now.
That is problem i am facing.
I am not doing anything in code more than setting content size.
If you need any other information, please tell me.

Comment: please add some code.

Comment: The view that you are hiding, is that the contentView of the scroll view? If so... You are going to need another view in between

Comment: @Rob, I guess I need to recuse myself from UIKit questions all together...

Comment: @BH4451 Please share more details (esp code). This raises more questions than it answers, but perhaps showing source code may remove the ambiguity. Also, I presume that you're using auto layout.

Comment: @Rob I am only a Mac developer now and haven't used UIKit for a few years... so when something works a little bit differently for NSSomething vs UISomething I tend to think that is works the NSSomething way.

Answer (score 6):

The `contentSize` in iOS 6 "auto-sizes" itself with auto layout. This means you cannot set the `contentSize`. There are hacks that suggest setting it in the `viewDidAppear` call, but I would avoid this. If you read the [iOS 6 release notes](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/General/RN-iOSSDK-6_0/index.html) (search for `UIScrollView` on the page) it gives you a couple solutions. One of them involve the `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` property.

Comment: I agree with your intuition here, but in practice, I've found that it doesn't recalculate the `contentSize` if I simply set the subview to be hidden or with an alpha of zero. It only works gracefully if I reset the height constraint of the item being hidden. Curiously, even if I remove the subview, it won't recalculate the `contentSize` unless there's something _else_ on the scrollview that has constraints that might lead the `contentSize` to be recalculated. If the removed subview is the last one, `contentSize` isn't recalculated (though you can reset manually).

Comment: Never said it worked correctly. Just stating the "reason" why it doesn't work in iOS 6. The release notes mention a way to work around this.

Comment: Hi, i figure out it is setting contentSize to UIScrollView frame size. How and When it is setting?

Comment: After viewDidLoad, but before viewWillAppear/viewDidAppear. It's better to set the `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` property. See answer for more info.

Comment: "The contentSize in iOS 6 'auto-sizes' itself with auto layout" — Love you man, I would totally mark this answer as the correct one.

Answer (score 5):

Remove all your code related to sizing the scrollview content size. Autolayout uses this while you are scrolling now. After you do this add the following code

```
// Add 200 points to the bottom of the scroll view
[self.scrollView setContentInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 200, 0)];
self.scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints= NO;
```

Answer (score 0):

Without any code, I'll hazard a guess...

This would be typical in a case if your `contentSize` doesn't exceed the size of your `UIScrollView`.  If you were to, say, hide your view, then change the size of your scroll view and your scroll view exceeds or is equal to your `contentSize`, then you will not have anything to scroll.

Another possibility is if you have disabled user interaction.